# SQLite : How to populate a boolean field on a pojo, from a subQuery

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-room

I want to return a list of posts like.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM posts")
List<Post> getPosts()
```

I have a pojo.

```
post {
   name:String
   id :String
   postUid:String
   userHasNewContent:Boolean
}
```

Now, I want every post in the list to have the `userHasNewContent:Boolean`, populated by checking if the user who owns this post has new content(Not older than a week)

So I tried.

```
@Query("SELECT *,
       (SELECT content_uid FROM content WHERE content_uid = postUid AND
        contentTime < :aWeekAgo)AS userHasNewContent 
      FROM posts")
List<Post> getPosts(String aWeekAgo)
```

WHERE content is:
   content{
       contentTime:Long //Unix Timestamp
       id:String
   }

AND

```
public static Long aWeekAgo() {
        long day = (1000 * 60) * 60 * 24;
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - day * 7;
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work as expected, am I doing this the way?

**Edit**
Ok, after writting the question, it's now clear what I want to do. Here's the short version.

```
//Get all posts
@Query("SELECT * FROM posts")
List<Post> getPosts()

//Then loop through them.
@Query("SELECT count(*) FROM content WHERE contentId :contentUID AND soundTime < : aWeekAgo")
int checkIfUserHasNewContent(String uid, long aWeekAgo);


List<Post> postsWithNewContentIndicator = new ArrayList<>();
for (Post post : postsFromDb) {
    post.userHasNewContent(checkIfUserHasNewContent(post.getUid()) > 0);
    postsWithNewContentIndicator.add(post);
}
```

**So, but I want to do this with a single query and not use this loop.**

Comment: What format are you storing your times in? Is it the exact same format used by `aWeekAgo`? Is it a format that can be meaningfully compared for inequality?

Comment: Ohhh that, it's unix timestamp, in `long`, so the `aWeekAgo` is ` System.currentTimeMillis() - ( (1000 * 60) * 60 * 24 * 7)`

Comment: Cool. All too often you see people trying to use things like `MM-DD-YYYY`, which doesn't work right at all. The Unix time is usually in seconds, not milliseconds, but as long as it's that way consistently...

Comment: @Shawn yeah, what do you think I should do?

Comment: SQLite uses INTEGERs instead of BOOLEANs. Therefore, convert your incoming data to 1 and 0 if you get True or False, respectively.

Comment: Could you please provide us with schemas of your **content** and **posts** tables? At first sight - right now your subquery returns list of content_uids, but it should return just one value 0(if there isn't any data) or 1(if there are some data).

Comment: @Relm Have you checked the answer I posted?

Comment: @Anees I've improved the question, please see the last edit.

Comment: The answer I've posted already meets the requirement. You will get all the posts along with a boolean value which indicates whether the post owner has a new post  in a single query. Please check it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to rewrite the query as the following

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  (
    (
      SELECT 
        COUNT(*) 
      FROM 
        (
          SELECT 
            content_uid 
          FROM 
            content 
          WHERE 
            content_uid = postUid 
            AND contentTime > : aWeekAgo
        )
    )> 0
  ) AS userHasNewContent 
FROM 
  posts
```

Comment: Ok, this does it, but something is wrong with time, seems to disregard it and get returns true even if user has content that is more than a week. Also I changed the code to. `"SELECT *, " +
     "(SELECT COUNT(content_uid) FROM content WHERE content_uid = uid AND content_time < :aWeekAgo)> 0 " +
     "AS userHasNewContent " +
     "FROM posts ORDER by time DESC"`

Comment: @Relm  I thought it was the only problem and all other parts are fine. Can you specify what contentTime and aWeekAgo actually are? Their datatypes and a set of sample values? If they are timestamps, I think you need a > instead of <. I've updated it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your sub-query should be written as a case:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
   SELECT content_uid FROM content WHERE content_uid = postUid AND
       contentTime < :aWeekAgo
)
THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END
```

Comment: Sqlite doesn't have a "BIT" type.

Answer (score 0):

Assume post and user is 1 to 1, you can do it with a join.

```
SELECT posts.name, posts.uid, posts.postUid, 
  (content.contentTime < :aWeekAgo) as userHasNewContent
FROM posts inner join content on content.uid = post.uid
```

If user to posts are 1 to n, you will need to use group and having too.